# Go off vs go on?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

So I've just seen an English paper listing many of the phrasal verbs. Two of those were "Go off: happen" and "Go on: happen". So either go off or go on means happen? Is this true? I'm a bit confused, please help me if you can. Thanks.

Comment: They're used in different contexts - fireworks go *off* while performers go *on* (there's probably a better example). And there are some who go *on and on* :) . The choice might be *up* to you, or the decision might come *down* to you. [*English, as she is spoke*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_As_She_Is_Spoke), as it were.

Comment: Really common verbs like _go, come, have, do, look, hear, take, give, bring, get, seem,_ and some others (note how short they are) are likely to be used in idioms. One of the most common kinds of idiom is phrasal verbs, which use really common prepositions like _off, on, up, down, over, under, out, in,_ and some others, almost always idiomatically. Combining these two idiom chunks -- _come/go_ plus _off/on_ leads to any number of idiomatic senses, all of which have to be learned individually. That's the problem with idioms.

Comment: The solution is to get a dictionary of phrasal verbs with examples in context. One-word glosses are not useful except as placeholders.

Comment: @Lawrence - also in British English (don't know about others) if events/things have been happening, we can say they have been _going on_.

Comment: I wonder if there's a word for situations where things that should be opposites are the same. Sort of like [contronyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym#Examples_of_English-language_auto-antonyms), but the opposite.

Comment: *I've just seen an English paper listing many of the phrasal verbs.* There is no point in quoting words or phrases without context. The importance of context in English cannot be overstated. To "**go off**" can mean **to turn rotten; to explode; to depart; to become adverse to** and probably many other things **depending on the context.**

Comment: Also, _go off_ and _go on_ might both mean _happen_ but don’t mean the same thing. Go off indicates _starting_ while _go on_ indicates _continuing_

Answer (score 1):

In comments, John Lawler wrote:

> Really common verbs like *go, come, have, do, look, hear, take, give, bring, get, seem,* and some others (note how short they are) are likely to be used in idioms. One of the most common kinds of idiom is phrasal verbs, which use really common prepositions like *off, on, up, down, over, under, out, in,* and some others, almost always idiomatically. Combining these two idiom chunks -- *come/go* plus *off/on* leads to any number of idiomatic senses, all of which have to be learned individually. That's the problem with idioms.

And:

> The solution is to get a dictionary of phrasal verbs with examples in context. One-word glosses are not useful except as placeholders.

Comment: off = away from; off the track = away from the track. The car went off the road. At the same time, the 'bomb went off" means it exploded.  We may possibly read it  close to the meaning 'happen'.  Go on = continue, happen, etc.  While complimenting, we say, "Hi guys; good work; just go on..."

Answer (score 1):

There *are* subtleties involved with the use of the multi-word verb 'go off' in the intransitive sense of 'occur'.

[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-off) lists this sense:

> **go off** {phrasal verb} [less ambiguously, multi-word verb]
>
> ...
>
> {happen}: to happen in a particular way:
>
> - *The protest march went off peacefully.*

Merriam-Webster shows that the usage is not purely British, and refines the definition:

> **go off** {intransitive verb}
>
> ...
>
> 5: to follow the expected or desired course : PROCEED
>
> - *the party went off well*

A complication here is that replacement by 'took place' can occur in the CED example:

- *The protest march went off peacefully.* ⇔ *The protest march took place peacefully.*

But not in the M-W example:

- *The party went off well.* ⇔ **The party took place well.*

It is probable that 'go off', having the implications of 'in a particular way', licenses 'well' whereas unmarked 'occur', 'happen' and 'take place' don't. Note that M-W is over-prescriptive here, as '... the rally went off rather badly' is totally idiomatic, at least in the UK.

Going further, it seems that 'go off' in this sense *requires* or at least is almost always accompanied by an (evaluative) adverbial.

- *The event went off rather well, don't you think?*
- *It all went off beautifully / like a dream.*
- *Let's hope it all goes off without a hitch.*
- ??*It should go off later today.*
- **Have the finals gone off yet?*

....................

Similarly, 'go on' and 'happen', while being fairly close synonyms, are not fully interchangeable:

- ***What is** going on here?* ⇔ *What *is* happening here?*
- *There's a lot going on at the moment.* ⇔ *There's a lot happening at the moment.*
- *He's a lot going on at the moment.* ⇔ ??*He's a lot happening at the moment.*
- **What do you think will go on next?* ⇔ *What do you think will happen next?*

The nominalisation 'goings on' carries a strong flavour of human or at least sentient involvement, and this is in some degree common to the verbal usages. The last example, being pretty unmarked for this, needs 'happen' or in a formal register 'occur'.

Comment: This helps but I'm still confused, e.g. in this example from a smoke alarm's fine print safety & regulatory guide: "Burning material creates combustion particles which _could cause your smoke alarm to go off unnecessarily."_ There's similar usage in a sprinkler controller's instructions. These devices are said to "go off" when they literally turn on. How can readers and writers be clear about turning on vs. turning off? The smoke alarm goes <off> when the smoke clears.

Comment: @Jerry101 'Go off' = 'activate (intransitive)'. 'Turn on' (your second example) doesn't work well here. When a firework or bomb _goes off_, it explodes. When an alarm _goes off_, it activates in the sense of displays activity: sounds and/or flashes. With a smoke alarm say, you might need to turn it on (essentially, complete a circuit) after fitting, but it will only _go off_ when it is tested or when smoke triggers it.

Comment: So to clarify the distinction, the smoke alarm device _"goes off"_ means its alert sound _turns on._ Phrasing aside, the device turns _on_ the power to its noisemaker component which turns _on_ the loud alert sound. When the smoke clears and the device turns _off_ its alert sound, do we say the smoke alarm device _goes on_ or something else? If we say the sprinkler head _goes off_ (activates) when the power goes _on_ and it starts spraying water, do we say it _goes on_ when it stops spraying water? (I'm trying to clarify the question, not to be disagreeable.)

Comment: '... its alert sound turns on' is not idiomatic. 'Sounds' would be the usual verb.